# Sql Statement to get customer who didn't place any order monthly (with month also showed)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, count

I have a customer table and an orders table
In this case I would like to have a monthly report about how many customer didn't place any order
Like this
Month  Number of inactive customer

I have written a query like this:

> ```
> SELECT     Count (distinct Persons.id), Month (Orders.OrderDate)
> FROM       Persons
> LEFT JOIN  Orders ON Persons.id = Orders.Person_id
> WHERE      Orders.Person_id IS NULL;
> Group By   Month (Orders.OrderDate)
> ```

Due to the condition IS NULL, then the result of Month (OrderDate) is also NULL
How should I let the month also be displayed?
I am using tsql

Comment: You need to `CROSS JOIN` to a calendar table, or distinct list of all the relevant month's start and end dates first, then include that in the `ON` to your `Orders` table.

Comment: @Larnu Hi, thanks for your reply, I am using tsql, cross join might not be possible or?

Comment: `cross join` is supported in t-sql

Comment: *"cross join might not be possible or"* Why not? a `CROSS JOIN` between your `Persons` and Calendar object, and then `LEFT JOIN` to your `Orders` table.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: Please define "how many customer didn't place any order".  In my experience, a customer is precisely those people who *place an order*, so the number is `0`.  Do you mean the total number of people minus the number who placed an order?

Comment: @KumarHarsh yep, I tried the GMB's solution with `CROSS JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`, it has worked

Comment: @GordonLinoff imagine a website like Amazon, people register there as member, but not every member orders things every month, I want to find out how many of them didn't place any order in each month.

Answer (score 2):

If you have at least one order per months in table `orders`, then you can `cross join` the persons with the distinct months, and filter on inactive clients with a `not exists` condition:

```
select d.ordermonth, count(*) no_inactive_clients
from persons p
cross join (select distinct datefromparts(year(orderdate), month(orderdate), 1) ordermonth from orders) d
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from orders o 
    where 
        o.orderdate >= d.ordermonth 
        and o.orderdate < dateadd(month, 1 d.ordermonth)
        and o.person_id = p.id
)
group by d.ordermonth
```

If there are months without any order, they will not show in the resultset though. In that case, you need a calendar table instead; you can store it permanently, or generate it with a recursice CTE or a tally.

Comment: what difference does it make, if I replace the where condition `o.orderdate >= d.ordermonth 
        and o.orderdate < dateadd(month, 1 d.ordermonth)` with `o.orderdate=d.ordermonth` ? I have saved all the orders during the selected time in an temporary table, so in #orders there is only orders I want for certain months

Comment: @Olivia: `d.dt` is the first day of the month, so you want to search for orders within that month, not only on the first day  the month.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a list of dates.  One method is a recursive CTE to generate the list.  Then count the total number of people and subtract the ones who have not made an order:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(date, '2019-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < getdate()
     )
select d.dte, p.total - count(distinct o.personid)
from dates d left join
     orders o
     on o.orderdate >= d.dte and
        o.orderdate < dateadd(month, 1, d.dte) cross join
     (select count(*) as total from person) p
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```

Actually, if someone places an order very month, then there is no need for the CTE:

```
select datefromparts(year(o.orderdate), month(o.orderdate), 1) as yyyymm,
       p.total - count(distinct o.person_id)
from orders o cross join
     (select count(*) as total from person) p
group by datefromparts(year(o.orderdate), month(o.orderdate), 1), p.total
order by min(orderdate);
```